# Word for attacking a mount in combat?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, attacking the horse of a mounted soldier, blowing up a motorcycle underneath someone, etc.

The actual implementation would be the word alone, as it'd act as a keyword in a game - for example "Attack", "Defend", "Item" "Flee", "attack a foe's mount".

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word/phrase would be used. Also you should narrow the scope to a single question as the Stack Exchange format doesn't work well with multiple questions in the same thread.

Comment: In the US South, you would *tump* them, alas it only works in the South. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few options.
The first one is straightforward:

- [dismount](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dismount)

  > to bring or throw down, as from a horse; unhorse; throw:
  > *The horse twisted and bucked and finally dismounted its rider.*

Similarly (note the specific synonym at the end):

- [unseat](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unseat)

  > to dislodge from a seat, especially to throw from a saddle, as a rider; unhorse.

For animals, the following could also work:

- [hobble](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hobbling)

  > to cause to limp.
  > to impede; hamper the progress of.

  Note that it usually specifically means:

  > to fasten together the legs of (a horse, mule, etc.) by short lengths of rope to prevent free motion.

I'm mentioning this because I'm rather certain I saw it used in a video game once, where it referred to the immobilization of human(oid)s (also in a broader, bloodier way).

And here are a couple of more generic options, that might work with vehicles as well:

- [immobilize](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/immobilize)

  > 1. to make immobile or immovable; fix in place.
  > 2. to prevent the use, activity, or movement of.
  > 3. to deprive of the capacity for mobilization.
- [oust](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oust)

  > to expel or remove from a place or position occupied

Comment: One downside of "dismount" is that the intransitive meaning ("get off one's own horse/bike/etc.") is more common.  Another is that "dismount" isn't equivalent to "attack", more to "attack successfully". "Unseat" may be your best option, as it doesn't have the first of these issues (though it still has the 2nd)

Comment: @PeterJennings It's mentioned under 'unseat' :)

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about a method of attack, how about:

> **dismount**, *v.*
> **II.** *transitive.*
> **5. a.** (*causal*) To throw down from a horse, etc.; to unseat, unhorse.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>